# How do I make free/busy checks work with the non-default calendar on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

My default calendar is my main/private calendar, but I want to share a second calendar and have it report proper free/busy times. When I share it and other people try to invite me, it says it can't get the free/busy times, but when I share my main calendar, it works (getting free/busy times from that calendar). I want the information to come from the other other.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a bridge between your two calendars to share your availability. If you don't mind, it seems that there are third party's who can do that: [YouCanBook.me](https://youcanbook.me/feature/direct/) and [Timely](https://help.gettimely.com/article/105-timely-and-google-calendar-two-way-overview) - and I'm sure there are more. Is this what you meant?